# Get MAC address of connected device

Tags: networking, ethernet

This is my network setup.
[image: This is my network setup]
In case of PC 1 send a packet to PC 2 and router 1 has a default route to Eth 1.
To transfer the packet from router 1 Eth 1 to router 2 Eth 1, the packet will be sent with the destination MAC of router 2 Eth1.

How does router 1 get the Eth 1 MAC address of router 2 without knowing the IP address?

Answer (score 2):

ARP.

The Address Resolution Protocol translates IP addresses to MAC addresses.

Comment: wich IP address used for the arp request?